# Can't clear setInterval on React Native Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having issues clearing setInterval in my React Native Project

Here is what I have tried

```
const options = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://demo.com/getInfo',
    headers: appHeaders,
  };

  const myInterval = setInterval(async function () {
    try {
      const results = await axios(options);
      if (Object.keys(results.data).length !== 0) {
        console.log('request successful');
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        'there was an error sending remote control access request',
        error,
      );
    }
  }, 4000);
```

Comment: is this printing success msg or error msg?

Comment: it prints request successful